A situation where a kid learns how to do drugs is "where/that" they have access to them. - which is correct?
Example 1

A situation that I often face is where I need to finish lab work in 10 minutes.


A situation that I often face is that I need to finish lab work in 10 minutes.

Example 2

A situation where a kid learns how to do drugs is where they have access to them.


A situation where a kid learns how to do drugs is that they have access to them.

Should I use where or that for situation in a cleft sentence?
What is the rule?

"A situation where .... is where ..."    is  awfully verbose.

Typically speaking when you describe the details of a "situation" you use "where" or "in which."  You don't use "that" unless "situation" maintains  indefinite reference (e.g. If you cheat, you will find yourself in a situation that will not help you succeed).  In other words, if you are describing the situation in detail, "that" is not to be used.
I think the source of your misunderstanding is a mistaken conception of cleft sentences.  Following the CMS:
The subject clause emphasizes new information that identifies a person, a place, a time, an object, a cause, etc.
The part of the sentence beginning with the relative pronoun usually refers to information already given
From this we can conclude that cleft sentences are used when referring to understood information between speaker and listener.  To take your first example, a cleft sentence would likely read: "It was a situation where I needed to finish lab work in 10 minutes."  Without that context, it is important to remember that English resists topicalizations that separate elements in a sentence from their descriptive clauses, meaning that it is unnatural to begin your sentence with "A situation that I often face" when you could just start with "I often face a situation where..."  This puts "situation" closer to its description.
Unfortunately your second example sentences are ungrammatical.  The only way to salvage them is to use "when," because the entire clause "when they have access to them" in this case would modify "situation," rather than the typical descriptors where/in which.  But even so the sentence is still unnecessarily wordy and the topic is unneeded.  You would simply say "Kids learn to do drugs when they have access to them."

I understand Examples 1 and 2 are unnecessarily wordy. But if I mean to say them like that in my speech. In that case, will Example 1 be correct English? For example, "one of the situations that often bother me is where I need to finish lab work in 10 minutes."

@vincentlin   : One of the situations which bothers me the most is when […]  in ten minutes

If you kept the wordiness you would be better off restating the the topic.  For example, your first sentences would read: "A situation that I often face is one where/in which I need to finish lab work in 10 minutes."

If you are playing a drinking game where your opponent must down a shot of vodka every time you say the word where, you are going to win the game, for sure.   But outside of such a contest, you could say

I often face the situation [where I have only ten minutes to finish lab work].

or

A situation I often face is [that I have only ten minutes to finish lab work].

"...the situation where..."   has situation being modified by a [relative clause].  where is like "in which".
"A situation I often face is..."  has a [nominal content clause] as predicate complement/subject complement.
